# Pythonic way to check returned value for None

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking for a pythonic way for the code below.

Function `foo()` may return an int or "None" and in that case "None" should be replaced by a default value.

I doubt that this can't be simplified and reduced to a one-liner, I just don't know how to do it ^^

```
def foo() -> int:
   # code


x = foo()
x = 0 if x is None else x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is plenty Pythonic and concise (2 lines). The only way to reduce it to 1 line is to use the walrus operator:

```
x = 0 if (x := foo()) is None else x
#         ^ assigns foo() to x and ^ x is reused here
#^but x is ultimately reassigned here
```

Comment: oh nice :) didnt know python had smth simliar to  a let/where operator. Thank you.

Comment: @d3nigma it was added in Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

you can use `or` operator. If the first argument resolves to False, second one is assigned. Example:

```
x = foo() or default_value
```

The issue with that is, if `foo()` will return `0` for example, default value will be assigned

Comment: This wouldnt be a problem at the moment since 0 is my default, but I can see how that could become a bug.